# C/Linux pointers and file reading - Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Working on teaching myself C in a Linux environment, and wrote some code to read/write from a file. The program compiles, but when I run it, I get a "segmentation fault." This is all the information I'm given; I don't even know where the fault is coming from in my code.

Since I'm new to C, I immediately went to google: `"Core Dump/Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you."`

This makes sense, and a lot of the examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/) show a few common errors, mostly to do with pointer variables. I've gone over my code a handful of times, but can't seem to find where I'm illegally accessing memory. Can someone with better knowledge of C help me find my error, and maybe also better explain how it led to a Segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insert(struct node*);
struct node * head = NULL;

void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Please provide the input and output text file names as %s name1 name2\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    FILE *f;
    if(!(f=fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        printf("Input file %s cannot be opened.\n", argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    struct node * line = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(line==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot do dynamic memory management.\n");
        return;
    }

    while(fscanf(f,"%d",line->value)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%d ",line->value);
        line->next=NULL;
        insert(line);
        line=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(line==NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot do dynamic memory management.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    free(line);
    printf("content:\n");
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        line=head;
        head=head->next;
        printf("%d ",line->value);
        free(line);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void insert(struct node * element)
{
    struct node * temp = head;
    struct node * pretemp = NULL;
    while(temp!=NULL && temp->value > element->value)
    {
        pretemp=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(pretemp==NULL)
    {
        element->next=head;
        head=element;
    }
    else
    {
        pretemp->next=element;
        element->next=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(f,"%d",line->value)` ==> `fscanf(f,"%d",&line->value)`. Unrelated, in C, `main` should *always* return `int`.

Comment: Your compiler isn't warning you about this? It should. If using gcc or clang, always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to help catch a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the statement `fscanf(f,"%d",line->value)`. `fscanf` expects the address of an int but you are giving it an actual integer. It's segfaulting because it's treating that int as a memory location and trying to write to it. Change it to `fscanf(f,"%d",&(line->value))` instead and it should work.